# How to start a fullscreen virtual machine via VirtualBox in the current Mac OS X workspace?

Tags: macos, virtualbox

Since I updated VirtualBox to 4.3.12, when I start a virtual machine in fullscreen mode, it launches a new workspace with it which is not practical. (Mac OS X 10.8.5)

Just changing the virtual machine View parameters "Switch to fullscreen" launches a new workspace.

I use two screens and I used to have my VM on left screen and my code editor on right screen to debug Internet Explorer.

Before that update, I could switch with CMD + TAB between the Virtual Machine and my others apps because they were in the same workspace. It was really useful.

I searched in all parameters I could find in VirtualBox and Mac configuration, then in web forums without any result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your VirtualBox is fullscreen.

Quit fullscreen with <kbd>"HOST"</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

That is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but my question was not only about how not switch fullscreen.

Actually, before this update I could have my left screen with VirtualBox in fullscreen mode and my right screen with my code editor from the host machine.
Since this update, if I switch VirtualBox to fullscreen, I have my right screen with VirtualBox fullscreen and my left screen becomes useless with a grey background.
I don't know if it is more related to Mac OS X workspaces but this happened since VirtualBox 4.3.12 update.

And I can't test this anymore, because I switched to another OS :/